# eclipse.log.level in Eclipse RCP config.ini file not working?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4, pde

I am using service Logger (workbench Logger) to log in Eclipse RCP.
I have used it many locations where it is used for logging `INFO`, `WARNING` and `ERROR` as well.
I had set `eclipse.log.level = ERROR` in the launch configuration (tab) of the product file. Now I expect it to log only `ERROR` logs in the log file.
But when I am launching from the product file it is logging all the `INFO` logs also. My understanding is wrong on `eclipse.log.level`? or anything else has to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a system property you set it with

```
-Declipse.log.level=ERROR
```

in the 'VM arguments' section of the 'Arguments' tab on the launch configuration.

Comment: worked ..my mistake I was thinking in it as config property

Comment: Note that this currently won't work with `-Declipse.log.level=DEBUG` or `TRACE`, despite the logger being quite happy to let you log at those levels. `INFO` being the default, the only ones that have any effect as far as I can tell are `WARNING` and `ERROR`.